Dialog in Compose with undesired gap when displayed inside a Transparent Activity
I have a transparent Activity in my code that has the following theme:
<style name="Theme.MyApp.Transparent" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
</style>

And that renders the following content:
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContent {
        MaterialTheme {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .background(color = Color.Green)
            ) {
                Dialog(
                    onDismissRequest = {},
                    properties = DialogProperties(
                        usePlatformDefaultWidth = false
                    ),
                ) {
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize()
                            .background(color = Color.Red)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

The problem is that on APIs like 29 (Android 10) and 30 (Android 11), a small margin to the RIGHT and to the BOTTOM is set to the dialog for some reason that is unknown to me:

It doesn't happen on APIs like 34 (Android 14).

What can I do to resolve that bug? I haven't found a fix to it yet.
